# SignalR - Exceptions Propagation to Client

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, signalr

I have a SignalR application with a .NET client. When an error occurs at the server I need to be able to handle this on client side. However, this is a bit difficult as Signalr always wraps all exceptions into an "InvalidOperationException" with a message like "UnknownUserException was thrown...", instead of actually giving me the `UnknownUserException`.

I'm not sure how to go about this?

An example which doesn't work right now (since `InvalidOperationException` is thrown instead of the actualy exception):

```
try
{
     await this.hubProxy.Invoke<Guid>("Authenticate", nww object[] { userName, languageCode, credentials });
}
catch(UnknownUserException ex)
{
     Toast.Dislay("Invalid UserName.");
}
catch(ConnectionError ex)
{
     Toast.Dislay("Connection Error.");       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On your server you can enable detailed errors:

```
Routes.RouteTable.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration
{
    EnableDetailedErrors = true
});
```

Keep in mind, by doing this errors thrown on the server will be passed over to clients which may reveal some unintended vulnerabilities in your server side implementation (just an FYI).

Comment: Is there some way I can hook into the exception handling and only propagate exceptions I know in a safe way, and wrap all others?

Comment: Kind of, you can create a hub pipeline module: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline and then tie into things like BuildIncoming to execute hub functions and catch exceptions that are thrown and decide whether to propogate them

Comment: I've added, `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true, EnableCrossDomain = true});` in `Application_Start` and recycled my app pool. Still getting `InvalidOperationException` instead of the actual exceptions. Anything I might have missed to do?

Comment: That should be enough, if you're not getting your errors you should file a bug

Comment: I have this same exact issue and we've always had EnableDetailedErrors on.  I get my exception with my custom message text, but the type is always InvalidOperationException.